# Как обернуть webpack в VS solution?

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, typescript, webpack

Есть приложение, например, созданное при помощи

```
create-react-app some-app --typescript
```

Хочу поместить его в solution в Visual Studio, но таким образом, чтобы в файле проекта не было перечисления всех файлов. Эта необходимость связана с несколькими причинами:

1. Файлов много, VS начинает тормозить.
2. Сложно поддерживать список файлов в актуальном состоянии.

Желательно при этом исключить из solution'а node_modules.

При этом:

1. VS должна понимать написанный код и корректно его подсвечивать.
2. Инструменты типа поска по solution'у должны работать.
3. VS должна понимать, откуда импортируются сущности и не подчёркивать импорты.
4. Ни компиляция, ни запуск *не требуются*.

Обращаю внимание, что речь идёт именно о Visual Studio, а не о Visual Studio Code.

PS: Это не самоответ, **жду более хорошие предложения**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе приемлемо работает вариант в виде проекта с типом Web Site (guid этого типа проекта {E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}), весь solution выглядит как-то так:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2012
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "sources", ".\some-app", "{A30B7751-6DC6-499C-9624-4E2F5BC58922}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/sources"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "some-app\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\sources\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/sources"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "sources\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\sources\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        VWDPort = "57365"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {A30B7751-6DC6-499C-9624-4E2F5BC58922}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {A30B7751-6DC6-499C-9624-4E2F5BC58922}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = TRUE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Структура фалов получается такая:

[image: скриншот структуры файлов]

Но из-за того, что node_modules исключить не получается, приходится задавать полный путь до папки с исходниками при поиске:

[image: скриншот настроек поиска]